# How to check whether age public key and private key couple with each other

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key, public-key, encryption-symmetric

Age is a practical toos for file encryption, here it is its presentation page: [age](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age).

With `age-keygen`, we are going to be able to create a couple of public key and private key together like below:

```
# created: 2024-02-14T17:14:05+01:00
# public key: age1zskjrcgkgqhjaksa22ze85wy0wy2xg8sf7j8fntdgz2d4h25rp9sz76q7p
AGE-SECRET-KEY-1SA9KV6M7C27GFW22ZXED69SAATLH3UMDUSN720AQR0JEN2YTU0MS7FFZA2
```

Where we are going to have a pair of public key and private key (`AGE-SECRET-KEY-...`). We can use these information for encryption and decryption, no problem.

But what bothers me is that I haven't found a way to verify whether the public key and the private key of age couple. A similar example in openssl is below:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -modulus | openssl md5
openssl rsa -in key.pem -noout -modulus | openssl md5
```

If the results generated are identical, we are going to be able to verify that `cert.pem` and `key.pem` are a pair. How can we achieve the similar functionality for age keys?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found a alternative way to test whether the public key and private key of age are of a pair. We can put it together following the format which they are created, and put it in ~/.config/sops/age/keys.txt. If it works with decryption like `sops --decrypt --input-type json --output-type json test_file.json > test_file_dec.json` where test_file.json is an encrypted file using the age public key in keys.txt, then we can say that the private key inside keys.txt are of the same pair of the public key inside. But it is still not a direct method to verify a couple of public and private key.